# Form labels not rendering with Django & WTForms

Tags: django, mongoengine, wtforms

I'm trying to use WTForms with Django & a MongoEngine/MongoDB database backend. The forms are outputting properly, but I can't for the life of me get the labels to show up.

Here is my template code:

```
{% load wtforms %}
<form>
    {% for f in form %}
        {{ f.label }}: {% form_field f %}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

This is what I am passing in the view:

```
form = StrandForm()
return render_to_response('create_strand.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

The StrandForm class I have tried both creating from the WTForm mongoengine extension's model_form class, and from WTForm's Form class. The label exists in the view, I can print it to the console and it shows the rendered form label, but somehow it gets lost when transferring to the template. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.4 has a new feature: `do_not_call_in_templates` attribute.

If you set it on `wtforms.Field` class, every child class inherits and all fields will work fine in django templates.

```
import wtforms
wtforms.Field.do_not_call_in_templates = True
```

Now following code works as expected:

```
{% load wtforms %}
{{ f.label }}: {% form_field f %}
```

Comment: This fixed a problem where I defined `nested_form = FormField(...)` in my form, and in the template: `{% form_field form.nested_form.nested_field %}` wouldn't show up until I did `wtforms.Field.do_not_call_in_templates = True`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today. It has to do with the way WTForms is programmed so that it will work with many different templating libraries. Django 1.3 will only see **f** as it's HTML string even though it has other attributes.

In order to fix this you must add a template tag to retrieve the attribute.

Add the following to your projects hierarchy:

- templatetags
- templatetags / **init**.py
- templatetags / templatetags
- templatetags / templatetags / **init**.py
- templatetags / templatetags / getattribute.py

Then in your settings.py file, add the following line to **INSTALLED_APPS**

```
'templatetags',
```

Open up getattribute.py and paste the following code:

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()

@register.tag
def getattribute(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, tag_object, tag_function = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag requires two arguments" % token.contents.split()[0])
    return getattrNode(tag_object, tag_function)

class getattrNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, tag_object, tag_function):
        self.tag_object = tag_object
        self.tag_function = tag_function
    def render(self, context):
        return getattr(context[self.tag_object], self.tag_function)()
```

This will allow you to use the follow code whenever you're inside a template and need an attribute that won't show up:

```
{% load getattribute %}
{% getattribute OBJECT ATTRIBUTE %}
```

In your case:

```
{% getattribute f label %}
```

Hope that helped!